# Maximize the number of Elements in the Array divisible by M

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, integer

I'm working on the following task.

> Given an *array* of `n` integers and two integer numbers `m` and `k`.
>
> You can add any *positive integer* to *any element* of the array such that
> the **total value does not exceed** `k`.
>
> The task is to maximize the
> multiples of `m` in the resultant array.

Consider the following example.

*Input:*

```
n = 5, m = 2, k = 2, arr[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Let's add `1` to the element `arr[0]` and `1` to `arr[2]` then the final array would be:

```
[2, 2, 4, 4, 5]
```

Now there are *four* (`4`) elements which are multiples of `m` (`2`).

I am not getting correct output.

*My code:*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        int m = 4;
        int k = 3;
        int count = 0;
        
        int[] arr = {17, 8, 9, 1, 4};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++) {
                // check initial
                if (arr[i] % m == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                // add
                arr[i] = arr[i] + j;
                // check again
                if (arr[i] % m == 0) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Final Array : " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println("Count : " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task boils down to a well-known Dynamic programming algorithm called [*Knapsack problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) after a couple of simple manipulations with the given array.

This approach **doesn't** require *sorting* and would be advantages when `k` is much smaller `n`.

We can address the problem in the following steps:

- Iterate over the given array and count all the numbers that are already divisible by `m` (this number is stored in the variable `count` in the code below).
- While iterating, for every element of the array calculate the *difference* between `m` and remainder from the division of this element by `m`. Which would be equal to `m - currentElement % m`. If the *difference* is smaller or equal to `k` (it can cave this difference) it should be added to the *list* (`differences` in the code below) and also accumulated in a variable which is meant to store the *total difference* (`totalDiff`). All the elements which produce *difference* that exceeds `k` would be omitted.
- If the *total difference* is less than or equal to `k` - we are done, the return value would be equal to the number of elements divisible by `m` *plus* the size of the *list of differences*.
- Otherwise, we need to apply the logic of the *Knapsack problem* to the *list of differences*.

The idea behind the method `getBestCount()` (which is an implementation *Knapsack problem*) boils down to generating the "2D" array (a nested array of length equal to the size of the *list of differences* `+1`, in which every inner array having the length of `k+1`) and populating it with maximum values that could be achieved for various states of the *Knapsack*.

Each element of this array would represent the maximum total number of elements which can be adjusted to make them divisible by `m` for the various sizes of the *Knapsack*, i.e. number of items available from the *list of differences*, and different *number of `k`* (in the range from `0` to `k` inclusive).

The best way to understand how the algorithm works is to draw a *table* on a piece of paper and fill it with numbers manually (follow the comments in the code, some intermediate variables were introduced only for the purpose of making it easier to grasp, and also see the Wiki article linked above).

For instance, if the given array is `[1, 8, 3, 9, 5]`, `k=3` and `m=3`. We can see `2` elements divisible by `m` - `3` and `9`. Numbers `1, 8, 5` would give the following *list of differences* `[2, 1, 1]`. Applying the logic of the *Knapsack* algorithm, we should get the following table:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

We are interested in the value right most column of the last row, which is `2` *plus* `2` (number of elements divisible by `3`) would give us `4`.

<sup>***Note:** that code provided below can dial only with **positive** numbers. I don't want to shift the focus from the algorithm to such minor details. If OP or reader of the post are interested in making the code capable to work with negative number as well, I'm living the task of adjusting the code for them as an exercise. **Hint:** only a small change in the `countMultiplesOfM()` required for that purpose.*</sup>

That how it might be implemented:

```
public static int countMultiplesOfM(int[] arr, int k, int m) {
    
    List<Integer> differences = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    long totalDiff = 0; // counter for the early kill - case when `k >= totalDiff`

    for (int next : arr) {

        if (next % m == 0)
            count++; // number is already divisible by `m` we can increment the count and from that moment we are no longer interested in it
        
        else if (m - next % m <= k) {
            differences.add(m - next % m);
            totalDiff += m - next % m;
        }
    }
    
    if (totalDiff <= k) { // early kill - `k` is large enough to adjust all numbers in the `differences` list
        return count + differences.size();
    }
    return count + getBestCount(differences, k); // fire the rest logic
}

// Knapsack Algorithm implementation
public static int getBestCount(List<Integer> differences, int knapsackSize) {
    
    int[][] tab = new int[differences.size() + 1][knapsackSize + 1];
    for (int numItemAvailable = 1; numItemAvailable < tab.length; numItemAvailable++) {
        int next = differences.get(numItemAvailable - 1);  // next available item which we're trying to place to knapsack to Maximize the current total

        for (int size = 1; size < tab[numItemAvailable].length; size++) {
            int prevColMax = tab[numItemAvailable][size - 1]; // maximum result for the current size - 1 in the current row of the table
            int prevRowMax = tab[numItemAvailable - 1][size]; // previous maximum result for the current knapsack's size

            if (next <= size) { // if it's possible to fit the next item in the knapsack
                int prevRowMaxWithRoomForNewItem = tab[numItemAvailable - 1][size - next] + 1; // maximum result from the previous row for the size = `current size - next` (i.e. the closest knapsack size which guarantees that there would be a space for the new item)
                tab[numItemAvailable][size] = Math.max(prevColMax, prevRowMaxWithRoomForNewItem);
            } else {
                tab[numItemAvailable][size] = Math.max(prevRowMax, prevColMax); // either a value in the previous row or a value in the previous column of the current row
            }
        }
    }
    return tab[differences.size()][knapsackSize];
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countMultiplesOfM(new int[]{17, 8, 9, 1, 4}, 3, 4));
    System.out.println(countMultiplesOfM(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 2));
    System.out.println(countMultiplesOfM(new int[]{1, 8, 3, 9, 5}, 3, 3));
}
```

*Output:*

```
3   // input array [17, 8, 9, 1, 4], m = 4, k = 3
4   // input array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  m = 2, k = 2
4   // input array [1, 8, 3, 9, 5],  m = 3, k = 3
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tR3)

Comment: If there's a problem with the answer, maybe you can find a minute to describe the issue.

Comment: 1/ Ok.  I was me.  Normally I and most just don't explain downvotes.  There are lots of discussion on meta about why it isn't wise to do so.  But since you normally write outstanding answers and I could be wrong I will explain.  I have looked at the last example answer you provided.  To me it just seems like it should be 4 based on my understanding of the question.  3 and 9 are already divisible by `m` so they shouldn't be touched.  That leaves 1, 8, and 5.

Comment: 2/ You can add `1 to 5 and 2 to 1`, or `1 to 8 and 2 to 1`, or `1 to 8 and 1 to 5` and  convert two more values that can be divided by  `m` .  But that exhausts  `k` or leaves a remaining value of `k` which can't be added to any other to make a value divisible by `m`.  Since I could be wrong, I edited your answer to undo my downvote.

Comment: @WJS There's a bug in Knapsack implementation - while attempting to "add" a new item in the knapsack we need to consider **previous** Max result (i.e. from the previous row in the table when the new item was not available) for the *size* equal to *currentSize - itemValue*, but the code was checking the *current row* instead, therefore it was possible to "add" the same item multiple times. I fixed that, now should work properly.

Comment: @WJS Regarding the votes, I'm familiar with discussions on meta and I understand the rational of not explaining the reason of not leaving a comment. While of voting down I'm not always leaving an explanation (because it's too glaring wrong, or some has already done it, because of low quality of the post which is obvious without a comment, there are too issues, etc.). The key point of my attitude to the answers I'm posting on SO - I wish to know if there's a genuine mistake, here it clearly was the case and I appreciate that you've pointed out at it.

Comment: @WJS And the issue is real, I'm OK with facing a negative vote as a consequence. When the source of the problem is clear, there's no reason for rumination, the decision boils down to either of two: the post can be improved, or it's not possible (or doesn't make sense for some reason). When post was improved, some people tend to withdrew their vote, some people don't, I understand and accept both. I've got feedback, if the issue wasn't contrived, that's a **valuable feedback** even if it was accompanied by a negative vote.

Comment: @WJS I hope my attitude is clear now, and I'm really grateful that you have spent your time explaining the mistake you've spotted.

Answer (score 0):

You must change 2 line in your code :

```
    if(arr[i]%m==0)
    {
        count++; // add this line
        break;
    }
             // add
   arr[i]=arr[i]+1; // change j to 1
             // check again
   if(arr[i]%m==0)
   {
       count++;
       break;
   }
```

The first is because the number itself is divisible.
and The second is because you add a number to it each time.That is wrong.
for example chenge your arr to :

```
int[] arr ={17,8,10,2,4};
```

your output is :

```
Final Array : [20, 8, 16, 8, 4]
```

and That is wrong because 16-10=6 and is bigger than k=3.

Comment: no. This is not the solution. because we have a one condition that we can add any positive integer to any element of the array such that the total value does not exceed k. so for this array `{17,8,9,1,4}` answer should be 3

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you aren't processing the values in ascending order of the amount by which to adjust.

To solve this I started by using a stream to preprocess the array. This could be done using other methods.

- map the values to the amount to make each one, when added, divisible by `m`.
- filter out those that equal to `m' (already divisible by` m`)
- sort in ascending order.

Once that is done. Intialize max to the `difference` between the `original array length` and the `processed length`.  This is the number already divisible by `m`.

- As the list is iterated

  - check to see if `k > amount needed`. If so, subtract from `k` and `increment max`
  - otherwise break out of the loop (because of the sort, no value remaining can be less than `k`)

```
public static int maxDivisors(int m, int k, int[] arr) {
    int[] need = Arrays.stream(arr).map(v -> m - v % m)
            .filter(v -> v != m).sorted().toArray();
    int max = arr.length - need.length;
    for (int val : need) {
        if (k >= val) {
            k -= val;
            max++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return max;
}


int m = 4;
int k = 3;
int[] arr ={17,8,9,1,4};
int count = maxDivisors(m, k, arr);
System.out.println(count);
```

prints

```
3
```